# How do I tell TypeScript what type something will be after using mapKeys from lodash?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have type Foo

```js
type Foo = {
    property_one: string,
    property_two: number,
    property_three: string,
};
```

and type Bar

```js
type Bar = {
    propertyOne: string,
    propertyTwo: number,
    propertyThree: string,
};
```

I use lodash's `mapKeys` function to turn the object from a `Foo` into a `Bar` like so:

`const myBar: Bar = mapKeys( myFoo, ( _, key ) => camelCase( key ) )`

but I get the TypeScript error

'Dictionary ' is missing the following properties from type 'Bar': propertyOne, propertyTwo, propertyThree.

How can I let TS know that the result of this `mapKeys` call will be a `Bar`?

Comment: Which version of load do you use? Please share full code

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to make such an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mapKeys` method of lodash returns a `Dictionary<T>`. Since the lodash can handle dynamic keys what you are trying to achieve is perceived as error by the Typescript Compiler

What you can do is that you override the return type and force the typescript compiler to use the type defined by you. You can use `as` keyword to tell the Typescript compiler to create a type assertion for the return type as follows

`const myBar = _.mapKeys( foo, ( k, key ) => _.camelCase( key ) ) as Bar;`